# Load React using by on click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wants to create a class which while load a react.js file into a div specified using the react i had not found any thing related to that on net.

Comment: Mate, you need to provide more details, what you are asking is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example:

Lets say you have 2 component `App and Child`, and wants to `render` child component on checking the checkbox, this is called `conditional rendering`.

**app.js** file, import file `child.js` in `App` component:

```
import Child from './child';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.showComments = this.showComments.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showComponent: false,
        };
    }

    showComments(e) {
        this.setState({
            showComponent: e.target.checked,
        });
    }

    render() {
           return (
                <div className="add_checkbox">
                   <span>Enable Comments</span>
                   <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enable_comment" onClick={this.showComments} value="enable_comment"/>
                   {this.state.showComponent ? <Child/>  : null}
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**child.js** file:

```
export default class Child extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return(
          <div>Hello</div>
       );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check `fiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ztx9kd1w/

Let me know if you need any help.